# Adding another line to a existing PHP Contact form

Tags: php, html, regex, contact-form

I'm working on a simple single page site from a template. The contact from had only name email and message body. I tried adding the number. It shows up on the page, and the line shows up in the email, but the number does not actually come through.

Ive copied and pasted the existing code for one of the other data points and changed the id, type etc. for the phone number.

The page is live on test.wotactical.com

EDIT: Added the javascript code

PHP

```
<?php

// Put contacting email here
$php_main_email = "ffl@wotactical.com";
$php_sending_email = "contact@wotactical.com";

//Fetching Values from URL
$php_name = $_POST['ajax_name'];
$php_email = $_POST['ajax_email'];
$php_phone = $_POST['ajax_phone'];
$php_message = $_POST['ajax_message'];



//Sanitizing email
$php_email = filter_var($php_email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);


//After sanitization Validation is performed
if (filter_var($php_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {


        $php_subject = "New WOtactical contact form from " . $php_name;

        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $php_headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $php_headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $php_headers .= 'From:' . $php_sending_email. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
        $php_headers .= 'Cc:' . $php_email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender

        $php_template = '<div style="padding:50px;">Hello ' . $php_name . ',<br/>'
        . 'Thank you for contacting us.<br/><br/>'
        . '<strong style="color:#f00a77;">Name:</strong>  ' . $php_name . '<br/>'
        . '<strong style="color:#f00a77;">Number:</strong>  ' . $php_phone . '<br/>'
        . '<strong style="color:#f00a77;">Email:</strong>  ' . $php_email . '<br/>'
        . '<strong style="color:#f00a77;">Message:</strong>  ' . $php_message . '<br/><br/>'
        . 'This is a Contact Confirmation mail.'
        . '<br/>'
        . 'We will contact you as soon as possible .</div>';
        $php_sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#f5f5f5; color:#333;\">" . $php_template . "</div>";

        // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
        $php_sendmessage = wordwrap($php_sendmessage, 70);

        // Send mail by PHP Mail Function
        mail($php_main_email, $php_subject, $php_sendmessage, $php_headers);
        echo "";


} else {
    echo "<span class='contact_error'>* Invalid email *</span>";
}

?>
```

HTML

```
        <!-- CONTACT1 -->
        <div class="edina_tm_section" id="contact">
            <div class="edina_tm_main_title_holder_wrap contact">
                <div class="number_wrap">
                    <span>06</span>
                </div>
                <div class="title_wrap">
                    <span>Contact Form</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="edina_tm_contact_wrap">
                <div class="short_info">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="subtitle">
                            <p class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.2s">Special order, FFL Transfer, consignment or just have questions? We're happy to help.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="main_input_wrap">
                    <form action="/" method="post" class="contact_form" id="contact_form">
                        <div class="returnmessage" data-success="Your message has been received, We will contact you soon."></div>
                        <div class="empty_notice"><span>Please Fill Required Fields</span></div>
                        <div class="wrap wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.2s" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.2s" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                            <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.2s" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                            <input id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Contact Number ex 123-456-7890" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
                        required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.2s" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                            <textarea id="message" placeholder="Type of inquiry, and/or details"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="edina_tm_button wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.2s" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                            <a id="send_message" href="#">Send Message</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /CONTACT1 -->
```

javascript

```
// -----------------------------------------------------
// ----------------    CONTACT FORM    -----------------
// -----------------------------------------------------

function edina_tm_contact_form(){

    "use strict";

    jQuery(".contact_form #send_message").on('click', function(){

        var name        = jQuery(".contact_form #name").val();
        var email       = jQuery(".contact_form #email").val();
        var phone       = jQuery(".contact_form #phone").val();
        var message     = jQuery(".contact_form #message").val();
        var subject     = jQuery(".contact_form #subject").val();
        var success     = jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").data('success');

        jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").empty(); //To empty previous error/success message.
        //checking for blank fields 
        if(name===''||email===''||phone===''||message===''){

            jQuery('div.empty_notice').slideDown(500).delay(2000).slideUp(500);
        }
        else{
            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            jQuery.post("modal/contact.php",{ ajax_name: name, ajax_email: email, ajax_phone: phone, ajax_message:message, ajax_subject: subject}, function(data) {

                jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").append(data);//Append returned message to message paragraph


                if(jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage span.contact_error").length){
                    jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").slideDown(500).delay(2000).slideUp(500);     
                }else{
                    jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").append("<span class='contact_success'>"+ success +"</span>");
                    jQuery(".contact_form .returnmessage").slideDown(500).delay(4000).slideUp(500);
                }

                if(data===""){
                    jQuery("#contact_form")[0].reset();//To reset form fields on success
                }

            });
        }
        return false; 
    });
}
```

Comment: If you use javascript to send the form, please provide the code.

Comment: @nr1chiefrocka Just added it. I'm thinking that's likely where my problem lies.

Comment: You need to modify the JavaScript and add your new field to it. It should be pretty obvious from the code what and where you need to modify it.

Comment: Hint, you need a new `var` near the top and you'll need to modify this line `jQuery.post("modal/contact.php",{ ajax_name: name,` by adding your new `var` to the end in the same format as the other variables you see there. You'll notice that things like `ajax_name` match what's in your PHP program.

Comment: @Dave I did go back and add/check that after the first comment regarding java. I've updated the code in my post with what I have now. Still no luck. It sends, and everything else works as expected, the email it send has hall the entry except for number (though it does have the prompt for it).

Comment: Right before you retrieve the `$_POST` variables do a `var_dump($_POST);` and make sure everything is making to PHP as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that if you might remove your regex pattern:

```
pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

here in this element:

```
<div class="wrap wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.2s" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
    <input id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Contact Number ex 123-456-7890" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
required>
```

and change it to just:

```
<div class="wrap wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.2s" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
    <input id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Contact Number ex 123-456-7890" required>
```

and test it, it would likely work. Or you might just test it with a `888-888-8888` number and see if it would work.

Comment: That was it, At first it didn't work (but i cleared my cache and it fixed it.